# Make Django Rest Api User Specific (get_queryset)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I want to make a Django rest api that is user specific so that I do /username at the end of the url.

Models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
age = models.IntegerField()
description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'User Profiles'

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_data(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
if created:
    user  = instance
    profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, age=18, description='No Description')

class Notes(models.Model):
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
parent_user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Notes'

def __str__(self):
    return self.note
```

Serializers:

```
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Notes
    fields = ('id', 'note', 'parent_user')
```

urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('notes', views.UserNoteView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

views:

```
class NoteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
queryset = Notes.objects.all()
serializer_class = NoteSerializer

class UserNoteView(NoteView):
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.parent_user.Notes.all()
```

My problem is that I can't do for example /William which is the name of my user, and user profile. Someone that knows this must be able to help!

Comment: what are you using for the frontend? you should do this there

Comment: Flutter + React

Answer (score 1):

Your notes `model` is incorrect. Change `OneToOneField` to `ForeignKey`. You can change it as below

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notes")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{note}".format(note=self.note)
```

Now, change your `viewset` as below

```
class UserNoteView(NoteView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.userprofile.notes.all()
        # or
        return Notes.objects.filter(parent_user__user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I assign multiple users to one note? How do I make a foreign key with multiple users*?

Comment: @WilliamAbrahamsson in that case you have to use `ManyToManyField` instead `ForeignKey`